# Dynamic subtraction in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table structure like this:

```
|Account |  MaxBalance | UsedAmount|
|--------|-------------|-----------|
Acc1           10000    2000
Acc2           20000    4000
Acc3           50000    2000
Acc3           50000    3000
Acc3           50000    8000
Acc4           20000    1000
Acc4           20000    5000
Acc5            5000    500
```

The output that I want is for same account `usedAmount` is dynamically deleted from new `remainingAmount`.

```
Account |  MaxBalance | UsedAmount | Remaining
----------------------------------------------
Acc1           10000      2000         8000
Acc2           20000      4000        16000
Acc3           50000      2000        48000
Acc3           50000      3000        45000
Acc3           50000      8000        37000
Acc4           20000      1000        19000
Acc4           20000      5000        14000
Acc5            5000       500         4500
```

Comment: Your results seem to depend on the ordering of the rows.  However, SQL tables represent *unordered* sets; there is no ordering unless a column has that information.

Comment: Ordering is based on Account

Comment: please provide your attempt to solve it, thanks

Comment: @DinkarBisht . . . Account is duplicated, so it is not an ordering for the table.

Answer (score 1):

This is really cumulative sum -- and then subtraction using that.  However, you need a column that specifies the ordering, so I'll assume you have one (otherwise the question doesn't make sense):

```
select t.*,
       (maxbalance - 
        sum(usedamount) over (partition by account order by <ordering col>)
       ) as remaining
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=81ff5c9041b98119c0388221a630c242) is a db<>fiddle showing that this does exactly what your question is asking for.

Comment: Not gonna work as for Remaining in one shot u r trying to update remaining for all records for same account. Doesn't matches expectation

Comment: @DinkarBisht . . . I have no idea what you are trying to say in your comment, but this answers the question that you asked.  I added a db<>fiddle to illustrate the answer.